# How to obtain the CADSOL package for solving PDE

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to solve a system of four two-dimensional nonlinear elliptic 
PDEs on a rectangular domain.
The finite element method cannot be used to solve this  problem.
The only package that can solve the system is the CADSOL package
that uses the finite difference method.
This package was developed in the Karlsruhe Institute of Technology
by Professor Schönauer in the early 1990s.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to obtain the CADSOL package.
I find no information about this on the Internet.
In particular, there is no information about this on the website
of the Karlsruhe Institute of Technology.

Can anyone help me to find or to obtain this package?

Comment: Whoever pointed you to that package is probably the person best suited to help you find it.

Comment: I found a university journal that says he turned 70 in 2003 (https://www.scc.kit.edu/scc/info/rz-news/2003/mai-2003.pdf). Your best bet is probably to contact his old group or department and hope for a response. There are multiple scientific papers that use this package, so maybe contact the authors of those. At this point it would probably be easier to read modern PDE literature and write something of your own.